# Multiple session Object in single page

Tags: javascript, vb.net, session-storage

I have two session storage defined in same page for two tab. I am checking some condition and assign value to session storage but problem is changing value of one session object also changes the value of other. The both session storage have different variable name and I am not sure why it is happening.

```
1-  sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabelForFlight', x);

2-  sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabel', x);
```

the both session stoarage are on separate JavaScript page

### for ActiveSortLabel

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var ActiveSortLabelFromPreviousReload = sessionStorage.getItem('ActiveSortLabel');

if (ActiveSortLabelFromPreviousReload != null && ActiveSortLabelFromPreviousReload != "") {
    $("#" + ActiveSortLabelFromPreviousReload).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");
}
else
{
    var x = $(".SortFilterMenu li").find("a[selected=selected]").attr("id");

    $("#" + $(".SortFilterMenu li").find("a[selected=selected]").attr("id")).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");

    if (x != null)
    {
        sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabel', x);
    }

    if(x==null)
    {
        var selectElementID = $(".SortFilterMenu li").find("ul li a[selected = selected]").closest("li").parent("ul").parent("li").find('a:first').attr("id");

        sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabel', selectElementID);

        $("#" + selectElementID).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");
    }
}
```

### for ActiveSortLabelFlight

```
(document).ready(function () {

var ActiveFlightSortLabelFromPreviousReload = sessionStorage.getItem('ActiveSortLabelForFlight');

if (ActiveFlightSortLabelFromPreviousReload != null && ActiveFlightSortLabelFromPreviousReload != "") {
    $("#" + ActiveFlightSortLabelFromPreviousReload).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");
}
else
{
    var x = $(".SortFlightFilterMenu li").find("a[selected=selected]").attr("id");

    sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabelForFlight', x);

    $("#" + $(".SortFlightFilterMenu li").find("a[selected=selected]").attr("id")).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");

    if (x == null) {
        var selectElementID = $(".SortFlightFilterMenu li").find("ul li a[selected = selected]").closest("li").parent("ul").parent("li").find('a:first').attr("id");

        sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabelForFlight', selectElementID);

        $("#" + selectElementID).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that what you think is happening is possible. You'll have to post more code however or else nobody will be able to tell what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Show us the code you are using. Also, 1 page will only have one session. You may write several key/value pairs, but there will only be one session.

Comment: You're entering the same value (x) in both variables. If it's an object reference, then both references stored in session will refer to the same object. You may need to clone your object here. if x is indeed an object rather than a primitive type.

Comment: I have update code

Comment: no they are different values

Comment: Do you have an x variable declared in the global namespace such that it may be getting confused? Perhaps try naming those variables differently (say x1 and x2) and then do some console output of their values, before and after setting in the sessionStorage, just to see what's being picked up. Also, you could change the two `if conditions (x != null) and (x == null) into a single if (x != null) {//stuff} else {//otherstuff}.`

Comment: Post your HTML. Why would you have this in HTML:`a[selected=selected]`? Anchor elements don't have a selected attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue stems from the two document.ready functions.

While I did not find a specific cause, I am posting this under answer only because there is a bunch of code that I couldn't add into the comments. I have combined and cleaned up your code into a single function. Please try this and report back:

```
$(function () {

    var asl = sessionStorage.getItem('ActiveSortLabel');
    var afsl = sessionStorage.getItem('ActiveSortLabelForFlight');

    if (asl !== null && asl !== "") {
       $("#" + asl).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");
    } else {
      var x = $(".SortFilterMenu li").find("a[selected=selected]").attr("id");
      $("#" + x).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");

      if (x !== null) {
         sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabel', x); 
      } else {
        var selectElementID = $(".SortFilterMenu li").find("ul li a[selected =  selected]").closest("li").parent("ul").parent("li").find('a:first').attr("id");
        sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabel', selectElementID);
        $("#" + selectElementID).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");
      }
    }

    if (afsl !== null && afsl !== "") {
      $("#" + afsl).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");
    } else {
      x = $(".SortFlightFilterMenu li").find("a[selected=selected]").attr("id");
      sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabelForFlight', x);
      $("#" + x).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");

      if (x == null) {
        var selectElementID = $(".SortFlightFilterMenu li").find("ul li a[selected = selected]").closest("li").parent("ul").parent("li").find('a:first').attr("id");
        sessionStorage.setItem('ActiveSortLabelForFlight', selectElementID);
        $("#" + selectElementID).addClass("ActiveSortLabel");
      }
    }
});
```